# When exactly does "overnight on" certain day happen?

Tags: time, dates

When somebody says for example "That will happen overnight on Wednesday", do they mean it will happen on the night between Tuesday and Wednesday, or between Wednesday and Thursday?

Comment: Wednesday and Thursday

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definition of *overnight* is "for the duration of a night" from [ThefreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/overnight)

"That will happen overnight on Wednesday"

It means this will happen on night between Wednesday and Thursday.

Comment: Sorry, did you mean Wednesday and *Thursday*, not Tuesday?

Comment: Yes see this ref. "At this very moment everything is standing awry to my eyes, for a man needs only to work late `overnight` in his writing of something or other for, in the morning, his eyes to be red, and the tears to be gushing from them in a way that makes him ashamed to be seen before strangers."